# Android: Design pattern to load a video ad in the background, while the users interacts with the activities

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

Following scenario:
I have an app with a few acticities. This app will use interstitial ads. These are rich content ads, typically video ads, which may take up to a minute or more to load, and are typically displayed at transition points (for example when the user moves from one activity to the next) in the app.

How can I achieve that?
Start a service when the app is started and request the video to load?
The SDK of the ad network in question (Greystripe) provides a listener class, with an event callback which is called when the video is loaded.
How do I notify the current foreground activity, that an ad is ready to displayed?
How to get a handle of the foreground activity from the service?

Or should I use an AsyncTask?
If I use an AsyncTask, where do I start the AsyncTask?
What would happen if the user switches activities? Does the AsyncTask know about that?
Isn't the AsyncTask destroyed, when the acticity which created it, is distroyed?